# How do I force a SIGILL to be sent to my program?

Tags: c, linux, macos, signals

I'm try to do some nasty hacky things with dynamically generated code, and I want the OS to send me a SIGILL when it reaches an unknown opcode. This would let me add a layer of meta-information about my program and so on.

However, for my little test program, it seems the OS is not sending the SIGILL, but rather sends either a SIGBUS, or a SIGSEGV. I'm guessing this means that the page in which the memory is located has an NX bit set on it.

Any tips on how to make memory executable?

For reference, here is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIGILL_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("Handling SIGILL\n");
}

typedef void(*FUNC)(void);

int main()
{
    signal(SIGILL, SIGILL_handler);

    int *bad = malloc(16);
    memset(bad, 255, 16);
    ((FUNC)bad)();

    printf("Returning like it's no big deal\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mprotect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) is your friend here. It is POSIX compatible (SVr4, POSIX.1-2001), so it should work under OS X and Linux.

```
int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
if (pagesize == -1) {
    perror("sysconf");
    exit(1);
}

/* allocate 16 aligned pages */
void *bad = memalign(pagesize, 16 * pagesize);
if (NULL == bad) {
    fprintf("aah, out of mem :-(\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (-1 == mprotect(bad, 16 * pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)) {
    perror("mprotect");
    exit(1);
}
```

should do it.

2nd edit: The compatibility of [`memalign`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) seems not to be that easy. I'd try `memalign`, `valloc` under OS X and Linux and if neither work, just use regular `malloc` and add enough bytes to the returned pointer so that it is aligned :-).

Comment: Consider also using [`mmap(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap) instead, which allows you to allocate memory with the appropriate protection bits in one system call, and also avoids unintentionally changing the protection bits on other memory that happens to lie in the same page.

Comment: I am curious to know if it worked. I use this approach with mmap but get only SIGSEGV.
        
`addr = mmap (NULL, 8, PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0); ((FUNC)addr) ();`

Comment: @DiwakarSharma your memory will come zeroed. Therefore you'll execute lots of zeroes which on Intel is the following instruction `0000              add [bx+si],al`. That means you'll dereference a pointer which might crash with `SIGSEGV` quite likely. To cause illegal instruction, you should fill the `mmap`ed memory with `0x0F0B` which is UD2 (the illegal instruction on Intel). Eg `*((unsigned char *)addr) =  0x0f; *((unsigned char *)addr+1) = 0x0b;` before executing it.

Comment: also you might want to add `PROT_READ`.

Comment: oh, and to write the memory, you'll also need `PROT_WRITE`. So `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but if anyone else is trying to force SIGILL generation then another alternative is to use inline assembly like the following:

```
asm(".byte 0x0f, 0x0b");
```

or

```
asm("ud2");
```