# How can I tell whether SIGILL originated from an illegal instruction or from kill -ILL?

Tags: linux, unix, signals, posix

In a signal handler installed through `void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);`, how can I tell whether a SIGILL originated from an illegal instruction or from some process having sent SIGILL? I looked at `si_pid` of siginfo_t, but this seems to be uninitialized in case an illegal instruction was encountered, so that I can't base my decision on it. - Of course, I'm searching for a preferably simple and portable solution, rather than reading the instruction code at `si_addr` and trying to determine if it is legal.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: ... in order to find the cause for a Xenomai thread termination where gdb says "Program terminated with signal 4, Illegal instruction.", but at $pc <pthread_setcanceltype@plt> there is a legal branch instruction in the core file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *bona fide* SIGILL will have an `si_code` of one of the ILL_ values (e.g., ILL_ILLADR).  A user-requested SIGILL will have an `si_code` of one of the SI_ values (often SI_USER).

The [relevant POSIX values](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html) are:

```
[Kernel-generated]
ILL_ILLOPC  Illegal opcode.
ILL_ILLOPN  Illegal operand.
ILL_ILLADR  Illegal addressing mode.
ILL_ILLTRP  Illegal trap.
ILL_PRVOPC  Privileged opcode.
ILL_PRVREG  Privileged register.
ILL_COPROC  Coprocessor error.
ILL_BADSTK  Internal stack error.

[User-requested]
SI_USER     Signal sent by kill().
SI_QUEUE    Signal sent by the sigqueue().
SI_TIMER    Signal generated by expiration of a timer set by timer_settime().
SI_ASYNCIO  Signal generated by completion of an asynchronous I/O request.
SI_MESGQ    Signal generated by arrival of a message on an empty message queue.
```

For example, the [recipe in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314270/how-do-i-force-a-sigill-to-be-sent-to-my-program) gives me ILL_ILLOPN, whereas `kill(1)` and `kill(2)` gives me zero (SI_USER).

Of course, your implementation might add values to the POSIX list.  Historically, [user- or process-generated `si_code` values were <= 0](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_424.txt), and this is still quite common.  Your implementation might have a convenience macro to assist here, too.  For example, Linux provides:

```
#define SI_FROMUSER(siptr)      ((siptr)->si_code <= 0)
#define SI_FROMKERNEL(siptr)    ((siptr)->si_code > 0)
```

Comment: Actually, the `si_code` for a signal generated by `kill` should be `SI_USER`, which is generally 0, but might be something else on some systems.  It will be distinct from all the `ILL_` values.

Comment: @nos, yes, but the OP's testing revealed that he can't rely on that field alone.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, of course. I was confused by the manual's wording _The following values **can be** placed in si_code for a **SIGILL signal**_.