# Linux: signal source

Tags: linux, signals

How does one find reliably whether a process received a signal due to its own misbehavior or was sent the same by another process? Basically, how does one determine whether si_pid field is valid or not.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care? What signal are you thinking of? Did you read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)? What is your application doing? A motivated kernel hacker could patch the kernel to add something sending a genuine-looking signal (which your app could not recognize as sent by outside)...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17368232/132382

Answer (score 2):

If `si_pid` in the `siginfo_t` structure matches `getpid()` then the process signaled itself.  Otherwise, another process did.  Since process IDs are unique at any point in time, a PID you have now could not possibly have sent you the signal at a time when it had your PID (because then it would have signaled itself and not you).

Edit:

As you have discovered, the `si_pid` field is not always set; sometimes it contains garbage values.  The first thing to check is that you have passed `SA_SIGINFO` in the `sa_flags` field of your `struct sigaction` when registering your handler.  Without this, your handler may not receive a `siginfo_t` at all.

Once that's done, there are rules for when `si_pid` is set, described here: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/siginfo_t.5.asp#Signal_Codes

In brief: `si_pid` should be set if `si_code` is one of:

- `SI_USER` - includes calls to `kill()`
- `SI_QUEUE`
- `SI_TIMER`
- `SI_ASYNCIO`
- `SI_MESGQ`

It is also set whenever `si_signo` is `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. When the process receives signal due to its own misbehavior, it doesn't have a valid si_pid. Michael Kerrisk's book says that si_pid is set when the signal is sent by kill or sigqueue. I have tested it, and I observed that when I had the process misbehave (by causing SIGSEGV), the si_pid didn't match the pid of the process. Thanks for your response, anyway.